# Take a picture on iPhone without showing controls

Tags: ios, camera

Is there a way to take a picture in code on the iPhone without going through the Apple controls?  I have seen a bunch of apps that do this, but I'm not sure what API call to use.

Comment: By "Apple controls", assuming you mean without using UIImagePickerController.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, there are two ways to do this.  One, available in iOS 3.0+ is to use the `UIImagePickerController` class, setting the `showsCameraControls` property to NO, and setting the `cameraOverlayView` property to your own custom controls. Two, available in iOS 4.0+ is to configure an `AVCaptureSession`, providing it with an `AVCaptureDeviceInput` using the appropriate camera device, and `AVCaptureStillImageOutput`.  The first approach is much simpler, and works on more iOS version, but the second approach gives you much greater control over photo resolution and file options.

Answer (score 37):

EDIT: As suggested in the comments below, I have now explicitly shown how the AVCaptureSession needs to be declared and initialized. It seems that a few were doing the initialization wrong or declaring AVCaptureSession as a local variable in a method. This would not work.

Following code allows to take a picture using AVCaptureSession without user input:

```
// Get all cameras in the application and find the frontal camera.
AVCaptureDevice *frontalCamera;
NSArray *allCameras = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

// Find the frontal camera.
for ( int i = 0; i < allCameras.count; i++ ) {
    AVCaptureDevice *camera = [allCameras objectAtIndex:i];

    if ( camera.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront ) {
        frontalCamera = camera;
    }
}

// If we did not find the camera then do not take picture.
if ( frontalCamera != nil ) {
    // Start the process of getting a picture.
    session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

    // Setup instance of input with frontal camera and add to session.
    NSError *error;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input =
    [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:frontalCamera error:&error];

    if ( !error && [session canAddInput:input] ) {
        // Add frontal camera to this session.
        [session addInput:input];

        // We need to capture still image.
        AVCaptureStillImageOutput *output = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];

        // Captured image. settings.
        [output setOutputSettings:
        [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:AVVideoCodecJPEG,AVVideoCodecKey,nil]];

        if ( [session canAddOutput:output] ) {
            [session addOutput:output];

            AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
            for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in output.connections) {
                for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts]) {
                    if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] ) {
                        videoConnection = connection;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (videoConnection) { break; }
            }

            // Finally take the picture
            if ( videoConnection ) {
                [session startRunning];

                [output captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {

                    if (imageDataSampleBuffer != NULL) {
                        NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput 
                                  jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
                        UIImage *photo = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];                                                                 
                    }

                }];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

session variable is of type AVCaptureSession and has been declared in .h file of the class (either as a property or as a private member of the class):

```
AVCaptureSession *session;
```

It will then need to be initialized somewhere for instance in the class' init method:

```
session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init]
```

Comment: Trying this code now, it all works up until `[output captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:...` but then stops, resulting in the photo never actually being taken. I added logging to the line immediately following this and it never gets logged. The code is verbatim what you wrote and I've confirmed the code up until that point works (added a button and hooked it up in the .xib, fires properly). I've also included AVFoundation.framework and AssetsLibrary.framework. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint at this line:

if (imageDataSampleBuffer != NULL)

Does it hit? If it hits, is error not NULL?

Comment: Is there a way for this to work while the app is in the Background mode?

Comment: Not sure. You can try recording video instead of still images. Recording starts while in foreground, the video frames will be received in background.

Comment: I'm trying the code as well, but I get the same problem as @TylerHayes. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Did you try my suggestion from June 3rd?

Comment: I could not get this running on my iPad with iOS 6.1 until I moved the setOutputSettings line after the "canAddOutput" call (into the if block)...

Comment: Has anyone found a solution for this? Neither the line if (imageDataSampleBuffer != NULL), nor the breakpoint is called..

Comment: What about this line: [output captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection...] does the breakpoint hit here? If you can give details on how the flow is executed, will be happy to help.

Comment: Solution for the problem noted by various posters that the callback block in [output captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:...] is never called: do not declare "session" locally in the function as         `AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];`
 (i.e. on the stack). Rather, declare it in the .h file as a property with `@property AVCaptureSession *session;` Otherwise, it will have disappeared by the time the callback block gets called. This is noted by the OP, but it would be helpful to add to the original code explicity for clarification.

Comment: Worked great.  A few notes: (i) you can move the call to `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection` to an `IBAction` for the "take picture" button.  Also, the very-top paragraph of the docs for `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` have the 5 steps you need if you want to put that session into a view (so it doesn't take up the whole screen.)

Comment: its working fine...but taking a image which is very black...not a clear picture

Comment: Any update why the image is black? Even user can not see what image has been taken?