# Phonegap/Cordova :: Programmatically take photo

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

This is the first time I'm trying to take a photo using Phonegap and I've got a small issue!

I can take a photo using the cordova camera plugin which opens the default camera app on the device. This works!

However, I would like to take a photo silently. For example, show a page of text and take a photo programmatically without the preview/default camera app ever showing.

Is there a way to do this currently? I've even looked into taking a silent video in order to extract a single frame.

Something along the lines of this ([Take a picture in iOS without UIImagePicker and without preview it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185126/take-a-picture-in-ios-without-uiimagepicker-and-without-preview-it)) but within Cordova/Phonegap is what's needed.

Comment: I'm affraid you'll have to develop your own plugin with native code.

Comment: I thought that would be the case, thanks anyway! I'll update with a fix once I've had a chance to build my own plugin. :)

Answer (score -2):

if you want to take picture specifically or screenshot will do the work for you????? because there is already plugin available for screenshot in cordova which doesn't need user interaction.