# How to customize screen brightness in iOS App?

Tags: ios, screen, sensors, light, brightness

it is possible to customize the screen brightness? 
specifically the other way around as ios does it. 
Darker the environment, the darker the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Use to improve screen brightness by adjusting the value from low brightness(0) to high brightness(10) in this way. : `[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:10.0];` For make low brightness set `[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:0.0];`

Answer (score 0):

This is rather complicated as you cannot get the sensor information you are looking for directly.
I have not done this myself but it should work in theory as the functions are there to do so.

You would need to take an image using the iphone's camera.
[Take a picture in iOS without UIImagePicker and without preview it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185126/take-a-picture-in-ios-without-uiimagepicker-and-without-preview-it)

Then process it according to this.
http://b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/obtaining-luminosity-from-an-ios-camera

You should be able to set brightness with something along the lines of

```
[UIScreen mainScreen].brightness = 0.4;
```

Test for proper brightness settings compared to luminosity.