# How to capture picture without user interaction in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I am working on an mobile tracing app for the iPhone. I want to capture the picture of user without user interaction. I have searched on Google but found two links that don't meet my requirements. I found that we can do this by using AVCam and AVFoundation. Is there any sample code related to this? Do you have sample code?

Comment: What do you mean by without user interaction? without click any button?

Comment: Ok, without user interaction, but you have to define a function to call when a predefined condition is satisfied.

take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14253204/screen-capture-for-ios

Comment: Please find my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62947941/2941150

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-takePicture` should do the trick in deed. You have to provider a custom `UI` for the camera controls, because otherwise (for me) it doesn't work. Check out the developer documentation in Xcode and search for takePicture. The method description has everything you need.

**Following provide simple logic for you:**

```
- (IBAction) showCameraUI
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker;
    // create and display picker

   self.imagePicker = imagePicker;
   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0
                             target:self
                           selector: @selector(targetMethod)
                           userInfo:nil
                            repeats:YES];
}

- (void)targetMethod
{
    [self.picker takePicture];
    // ...
}
```

**Other option is**

I Found That...

```
AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate
```

to take pictures automatically.

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer   
   fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

[Checke official document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and also [this link with source of code.](http://www.devsrealm.com/objective-c/direct-access-to-the-camera/)

**It is pretty simple and thank you:)**

Comment: but where should I dismiss the view

Comment: While I am using this its capturing multiple images

Comment: use this method - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info