# iOS: Can you record without displaying video?

Tags: ios, isight

Simple question but the keywords involved made Googling fruitless.

I'm just curious if the back camera on an iOS device can be recording/streaming video while the display is used for something other than a viewfinder.

Comment: upvoted for an interesting question. BTW, I'm hoping the answer is no... :- )

Comment: Ha, ya, I could see some sinister use-cases ... I'd just like to have the display connected to a projector showing graphics and use the camera to record reactions.

Comment: That's actually pretty cool, hope it works for you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is *absolutely*.

You can *hide* your capture/video view as the other answer suggests, but assuming that you already have permission to use video (and/or audio if it's an AV stream), you can do whatever you want.

Granted, I'd stick to "don't be evil" as your shtick, as one of the important, but purposefully vague app store submission guidelines is simply "they know something is wrong when they see it."

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25332809/take-photo-without-camera-application/25333588#25333588) for a very related question & answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily put a UIView on top of the camera.  look at using:

```
self.imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = myCustomView
```

You would just need some sort of trigger in there to start / stop recording:

```
[self.imagePicker startVideoCapture];
[self.imagePicker stopVideoCapture];
```