# Without Open Camera click image and save in phone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How to capture image without open camera and save in phone in ios using objective C? I am trying to implement this functionality for using when click to lock your phone your device camera take a picture and save in your phone.

Comment: you want to take screenshot of the phone view?

Comment: here, Apple's [Developer Guidline](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/TakingPicturesAndMovies.html) from here you just do not need to show preview.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20934187/653513

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694859/ios-taking-photo-programmatically