# handling captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:completionHandler:

Tags: ios, xcode

Ive been trying to set up a small iOS method that takes a picture automatically when user opens the app. After much research i finally found this [iOS taking photo programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694859/ios-taking-photo-programmatically) and after a little more i found this from apple https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html can someone help me get started in setting up a method for `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:completionHandler:`
i don't want any interaction from said user. thanks

Comment: Why would you need the capture to be asynchronous?

Comment: i would like to take a picture programmatically without  any user input

Comment: You don't need to capture the image asynchronously for that... Just create a uiimagepicker as described in the 2nd answer of iOS taking photo programmatically and call takePicture: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23312505/2274694

Comment: Id like to use AvFoundation. that method didn't work either, its just opened the camera. I think it'd be fun to play with the device snapping a picture onload instead of user interaction and am still looking for a specific method

Comment: id like to use whatever is easiest and a lot of other answers I read on this site point to AVFoundation over UIImagePicker for creating customizable instances of camera functionality stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you seem to want to do the call asynchronously and using  `AVFoundation`, I still recommend simply using a `UIImagePickerController` in this case, ex:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // If the device has a camera...
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

        // Create an image picker
        UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePickerController.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
        imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;
        imagePickerController.delegate = self;

        [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:^{

            // And take the picture after a short delay
            // to give the view and image picker time to get
            // ready
            [self performSelector:@selector(takepic:) withObject:imagePickerController afterDelay:2];
        }];
    }
}

// Automatically take the picture using the 
// image picker passed in as a parameter
- (void)takepic:(UIImagePickerController*)imagePickerController {
    [imagePickerController takePicture];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    // ... Do whatever with the image ...

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```