# How to move another ViewController after taking photo without click on UsePhoto in ios?

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I don't want to click on UsePhoto after taking the photo by using this method [self.imagePicker takePicture];
 how can i achive this?

Comment: I don't understand your problem: In some way, you have to say to the UIImagePickerController that you want to use the presented image. So, why not use that button?

Comment: After taking photo i don't want to click USePhoto.

Comment: If you dont want to usephoto, dont take a photo. or click cancel.

Comment: i think @User558 want to use the selected image without tapping the `Use Photo` button in `UIImagePickerController`.

Comment: @GeneCode with out clicking on Usephoto.after taking photo

Comment: @Mahesh yes Mahesh any solution for that?

Comment: Please follow the link- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694859/ios-taking-photo-programmatically