# Take a picture without open camera in Swift

Tags: swift, camera

Do you know if there is a way for shot the pic with front camera without show the view? Any code examples will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You can use an `AVCaptureSession` to take a photo or video without showing a preview on the screen. Follow a tutorial or download a sample app and try hiding or removing the preview.

Comment: > If you don't want the user to see the preview input you can just skip the set preview layer part of the code. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9695053/8126260) to the question how to take pictures programmatically.