# How to set an image on your device to a UIImageView in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiimageview

I want to be able to take an image that i have already captured on my ipad and set it to the UIImageView inside of my ViewController.  Additionally, I would like to be able to have a photo button icon in my TableViewController that will allow me to take a picture and save a name to the picture that will be the title of the TableViewer cell that you would click on to look at the picture.  I have already been able to use pictures in my supporting files as the images i set to the UIImageView but cannot figure out how to take pictures and save them to the UIImageView inside of the app.  If you could give me any advice, tips, or resources to look at it would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your'e talking about images from the device i.e the user photos, you should use:

1. UIImagePickerController - presents a picker for the user to choose a photo
   http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html

OR for direct access -

1. ALAssetsLibrary -

> access to the videos and photos that are under the control of the
>   Photos application.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
UImageView* imview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage alloc] imageWithContentsOfFile:fileName];
```

to create a view containing the image stored in file fileName.

For how to take a picture, have a look at [this S.O. thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237941/ios-take-picture).

[Here](http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/camera/taking-a-picture) you can find an example of the code to do both.